# PHP - SQL Prepared statement in db2/odbc (prevent injection)

Tags: sql, db2, odbc, prepared-statement

In my experience with MySQL I was never a user of prepared statements (I was front end mostly and only did queries for testing).

Specifically, I now have a site using a form that updates a DB2 database with odbc connections. I'm new to this world but I realize that my query below is injection vulnerable.

How would I change this to create a prepared statement?

```
  $connectionstring = odbc_connect(A4_ODBCLINK, A4_ODBCUSER, A4_ODBCPW);

  if (!$connectionstring) {
  die('Could Not Connect:');

  }

  $sql = " UPDATE " . A4F_CUSTMSTFC . "
        SET XBLZIC ='" .$_POST['zip'] . "'
        WHERE XCSTNO ='" .$_POST['uname']. "'";

  $queryexe = odbc_exec($connectionstring, $sql);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do something like this:

```
$sql = " UPDATE " . A4F_CUSTMSTFC . "
    SET XBLZIC = ?
    WHERE XCSTNO = ?";
$stmt = odbc_prepare($connectionstring, $sql);
$success = odbc_execute($stmt, array($_POST['zip'], $_POST['uname']));
```

For more, see http://php.net/manual/en/function.odbc-prepare.php but basically just put ? in place of variables that you want to bind later.

Comment: Awesome, thank you. That makes more sense than I originally thought!

Comment: So if I want to do this with 2 queries, I would just follow this but use $sql2, $stmt2 and $success2, for example?

Comment: Yeah. And the nice thing is that the statements ($stmt) are reusable. So the DB can optimize those queries and reuse them.

Comment: Though I suppose there is no reason for $sql to hang around. Once you prepare the statement, you don't need it anymore.

Comment: Oh ok so I could really do it either way, with new statements or reused ones

Comment: Yeah - if it's the *same* query with different bind variables, hold on to $stmt and reuse it. It'll be faster / less overhead.